# Firefox won't display my jquery added element, but Chrome will

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox

HEre is my function :

```
function addEventForm(jour){
    if(!$(".formEvent").length){
        jour.closest("tr").after("<form class='formEvent'><div class='curseur'></div></form>");
    }
    
    var percent = jour.offset().left-jour.closest("tr").offset().left+parseInt(jour.css("margin-left").replace("px", ""))+ parseInt(jour.css("padding-left").replace("px", ""))+parseInt(jour.css("border-left-width").replace("px", ""));
    $(".formEvent .curseur").css({"top" : "-15px" , "left": percent+"px"});
    $(".formEvent").show()
}
```

By invoking it on Chrome, everything is alright, but in Firefox, the element is added, but not shown. How to fix it ?

## EDIT

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/g45r4um2/1/

Comment: Can you prepare a Fiddle for this at https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: YEs, i've prepared that

Comment: Unrelated, but I just want to mention that when using `parseInt`, you might want to pass in the second argument: `radix` to make sure the conversion works as you expected (so use `parseInt(n, 10)` for decimal numbers). Also, as long as the string passed to `parseInt` _starts_ with a number, you don't have to filter it out - `px` will be dropped automatically as its not a number, so no need to `str.replace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it:
https://jsfiddle.net/g45r4um2/13/ In firefox it doesn't understand where it has to be placed, so you have to add **td** and **tr** tags. Infact if you inspect element form in your code it is under tbody > form and seems firefox doesn't like elements under tbody alone.

```
jour.closest("tr").after("<tr><td><form class='formEvent'><div class='curseur'></div></form><td></tr>");
```